# ¿Cómo puedo buscar y editar arreglos dentro de un archivo .txt en C?

Tags: c++, c

quiero hacer una agenda utilizando archivos y para esto tengo que buscar datos dentro de la agenda y modificar estos datos pero no encuentro como. Con "strcmp" no me ha funcionado, no se si es porque la pongo mal o porque no sirve para archivos, pues cada que pongo un nombre, aunque este correcto, siempre me dice que el usuario no existe. Me sería de mucha ayuda saber como se declara la función o si hay una función mejor. Dejo mi código para una mejor comprensión del problema (omití cosas como el menú para que se pueda poner mejor el código pero considero que no es importante):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct registro{
    char nombre[50], apellidoP[50], apellidoM[50], matricula[50], telefono[50], consulta[50];
    
}est;

int main(){
    int i=0, j=0, a=0, opc, menu;
    
    FILE *ptr;
    
    // Introducir datos
    
    ptr = fopen("archivo.txt", "a+");
            
    printf("Ingrese su matricula: ");
    gets(est.matricula);
    fflush(stdin);
        
    printf("Ingrese su nombre: ");
    gets(est.nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
                
    printf("Ingrese su apellido paterno: ");
    gets(est.apellidoP);
    fflush(stdin);
                
    printf("Ingrese su apellido materno: ");
    gets(est.apellidoM);
    fflush(stdin);
                
    printf("Ingrese su telefono: ");
    gets(est.telefono);
    fflush(stdin);
                
    fprintf(ptr, "%s%s %s%s %s%s %s%s %s%s", est.nombre, "\r\n", est.apellidoP, "\r\n", est.apellidoM, "\r\n", est.matricula, "\r\n", est.telefono, "\r\n");
                
    fclose(ptr);    
    
    // Buscar datos
    
    ptr = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");
                
    printf("Nombre del contacto que quiere buscar: ");
    gets(est.consulta);
                
    while(!feof(ptr)){
                    
        if(strcmp(est.consulta, est.nombre) == 0){                          
            printf("\n%i. Datos: %s\n", i+1, est.nombre);                           
            break;
                            
        }
                    
        else{
            printf("No se encontro el contacto");
            break;
        }
    }
                
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varias sugerencias antes de contestar:

- La consulta **no debería** formar parte de la estructura de un contacto, sino que debería ser una variable independiente.
- Tu código no tiene nada de C++, recuerda que C y C++ son dos lenguajes diferentes, cada uno con características propias. No es buena idea añadir las dos etiquetas en la misma pregunta
- No uses `fflush` sobre `stdin`. `fflush` solo debe ser usado sobre streams de salida, **nunca** de entrada.

Y ahora vamos a por tu problema:

No estás leyendo nada del archivo. El archivo podría contener videos de gatitos, y la salida de tu programa sería exactamente la misma:

```
ptr = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

while(!feof(ptr)){
    // operaciones varias que no involucran a ptr ...
}

fclose(ptr);
```

Te falta algo tal que:

```
fgets(est.nombre, 50, ptr);
```

Por otro lado, no podrás saber si el nombre se encuentra en la agenda o no hasta que no hayas recorrido la agenda al completo (o hayas encontrado el nombre, lo que suceda antes). Es decir, el mensaje de error **no puede** estar dentro del bucle:

```
int encontrado = 0;
while(!feof(ptr)){
    fgets(est.nombre, 50, ptr);

    if(strcmp(est.consulta, est.nombre) == 0)
    {
        encontrado = 1;
        break;
    }
}
                
if(encontrado == 1) {                          
    printf("\n%i. Datos: %s\n", i+1, est.nombre);                           
} else {
    printf("No se encontro el contacto");
}
```

Ahora bien, según el formato que has elegido para guardar la información, a cada contacto le corresponden 5 líneas. Esto quiere decir que tendrás que leer esas mismas 5 líneas para poder pasar de un contacto al siguiente.

Si no lo haces corres el riesgo de que el programa te encuentre a alguien por el apellido en vez de por el nombre, por ejemplo.